# API addition to web based application (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel-10

i have made a web based project on school managment system in laravel . Now i want to add API in it.what changes or addtion do i need to make in application for example in the routes or controller.

i have'nt tried anything . just want to add the functionality of API.

Comment: "Adding an API" really just means "making some pages that are intended to be used by automated programs, not human users". You will find lots of advice about how to *design* an API to make it useful, maintainable, secure, etc; and lots of tools and framework functionality to help *implement* those designs; but like the rest of your website, there isn't one right way to do it, or a single set of steps that every API project has to follow.